# Adding the value of character in c

Tags: c

I was to ask to add the value of a number character into an integer, does anyone know how to do that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char num[100];
    int sum=0,n;
    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&num);
        sum=sum+num;
    }
    printf("Total = %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: What was the reason to read number as `scanf("%s",&num);`? Use `%d` an no conversion needed

Comment: @Redline its already been answered thank u for your concerned

Comment: @vsh its already been answered thank u for your concerned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert a string into integer using (atoi) the numerical representation to add it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char num[100];
    int sum=0,n;
    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&num);
        sum+=atoi(num);
    }
    printf("Total = %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: Wrong type for `"%s"`: `scanf("%s",&num);` --> `scanf("%s", num);`..`scanf("%99s", num);` is even better.